# Can I use Flask-Caching without a Flask app?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, caching, redis

I like the caching style of the Flask-Cache. So I want to ask if it is possible to use the flask cache (e.g. in combination with redis) for regular functions without a Flask app?

Something like this:

```
from flask_caching import Cache

cache = Cache('redis_server', config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})

@cache.cached()
def get_data_function(timestamp: datetime):
    return data[timestmap]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see from the source code of [Flask-Cache](https://github.com/thadeusb/flask-cache/blob/1c60076b6d4c2df0ac1de54c59e63b4f780cecbc/flask_cache/__init__.py), passing the flask instance is needed for it to work.

Personally, when I have a python application requiring caching with Redis, I go with [Walrus](https://github.com/coleifer/walrus). You can find it's documentation [here](https://walrus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

The interface is quite similar to that of Flask-Cache so there won't be any issues in getting used to Walrus

Comment: That looks great. Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.